# MongoError: BSON field 'insert.documents.0' is the wrong type 'binData', expected type 'object'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[image]

I'm using node 18.7 on ubuntu. I'm trying to parse a bunch of csv files to objects and load into mongo db.  I'm trying to follow https://github.com/AbdullahAli/node-stream-to-mongo-db example 4 - Stream from a local file. I have created the collection in the local db

```
MongoError: BSON field 'insert.documents.0' is the wrong type 'binData', expected type 'object'
```

My code:

```
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const streamToMongoDB = require('stream-to-mongo-db').streamToMongoDB;

// where the data will end up
// const outputDBConfig = { dbURL : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/streamToMongoDB', collection : 'devTestOutput' };
const outputDBConfig = { dbURL: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/local', collection: 'devTestOutput' };

// create the writable stream
const writableStream = streamToMongoDB(outputDBConfig);


const main = async () => {
    const readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
    const writeFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/file2');

    await readFileStream.pipe(csv(), { objectMode: true }).on('data', x => console.log(x.toString())).on('error', err => console.log(err))
        .pipe(writableStream);
    console.log('finish');


}

main()
```

When I run index.js I get:

```
MongoError: BSON field 'insert.documents.0' is the wrong type 'binData', expected type 'object'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: might be helpful to show the sample data - the CSV data.

Comment: the stream-to-mongo-db link you provided shows examples of streaming JSON data, not CSV data.

Comment: I just updated the link, and to be clear I'm basing my code on example 4 but not using it in its entirety - I was using other packages before I found this

Answer (score 0):

Base on https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#api:

```
const csv=require('csvtojson')
const converter=csv(parserParameters, streamOptions)
```

The stream options are inside the csv object. After I saw this , I was able to change the code to:

```
await readFileStream.pipe(csv({delimiter:',',ignoreEmpty:true},{ objectMode: true })).on('data', data => console.log(data))
```

and it started working